# Error parsing JSON data using javas JSONArray

Tags: java, php, android

my main.java is:

```
    JSONArray jsonarray = new JSONArray(response);
       for(int i=0; i < jsonarray.length(); i++) {
           JSONObject jsonobject = jsonarray.getJSONObject(i);
           String description = jsonobject.getString("description");
           Log.i("description", description);
       }
```

my response from php is:

```
[{"description":"Casa Lis"},{"value":"69800 \u20ac"},{"color":"#FFFF00"},{"description":"Calle de Van Dick"},{"value":"47250 \u20ac"},{"color":"#FFFF00"}]
```

my log print is:

```
08-01 22:27:55.638: I/description(20896): Casa Lis
08-01 22:27:55.638: W/System.err(20359): org.json.JSONException: No value for description
```

Comment: Are you trying to read value for _description_ on all iterations over this JSON array? AFAIK only first occurrence will contain that value.

Comment: yes. you loop on your array, but only the first object has a description (btw, this is a weird format you are using. why do you have an array at all?)

Comment: ups, sorry my response will be: 
[{"description":"Casa Lis"},{"value":"69800 \u20ac"},{"color":"#FFFF00"},{"description":"Calle de Van Dick"},{"value":"47250 \u20ac"},{"color":"#FFFF00"}]

Comment: Make sure to properly format your programmatic outputs also make sure to use more concise question titles.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In [Android Developers](http://developer.android.com/reference/org/json/JSONObject.html#getString(java.lang.String)), you can see that if the key "description" does not exist, `getString` will throw a `JSONException`, which is probably the error you are getting for the "value" and "color" mappings.

You need to check that the `JSONObject` has a "description" key before getting it:

```
if (jsonobject.has("description")) {
    String description = jsonobject.getString("description");
    Log.i("description", description);
}
```